# How to add infinite sum of odd/even numbers with factorial?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Here's the question I need help:
Let X be a random variable with probability mass function:
$$p_{X}(n) = \frac{e^{-1}}{n!}$$
for n = 0,1,2,..., and $p_{X}(n)$ = 0 otherwise.
**Compute the probability that X is even.**

I know that the infinite sum of $p_{X}(n)$ adds up to 1, and that the sum can be split into 2 sums where n takes form of $2k$ and $2k + 1$. But I cannot figure out how to finish. The textbook solution is $1/2 + 1/2e^{-2}$.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's the general case! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the infinite series for $e^1$ and $e^{-1}$:
$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
e^1&+1/0!&+1/1!&+1/2&+1/3!\dots\\
e^{-1}&+1/0!&-1/1!&+1/2&-1/3!\dots\\
e^1+e^{-1}&+2/0!&&+2/2!&\dots\\
\end{array}$$
So dividing by $2$ gives
$$\frac{e+1/e}2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(2n)!}$$
and then dividing by $e$ gives the final result.